# Can you help identify these ships?

Tags: object-identification

Was browsing the web for a picture of "Highness Ser Armaduke" and stumbled upon this picture.

[image: Ships]

There are Star Wars ships, Star Trek ships, W40K ships, Babylon 5 etc.

Can these ships be identified by class?

If possible can the Universe the ship hails from and the possible ship name be identified?

(Obviously the ships on the right are pretty tiny so I understand if none of them can be identified.)

Comment: Link for where you found it? Might be some relevant information.

Comment: Helpful information at the following links: [Comicvine](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/forums/battles-7/the-borg-star-trek-vs-the-empire-star-wars-660699/), [Blockaderunner](http://forums.blockaderunnergame.com/index.php?topic=1873.45) and [Star Trek Minutiae](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/comparison/index.html).

Comment: as stated found it by pure accident. that one was from a thread on https://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/imperium-of-man-v-borg-collective-wh40k-star-trek.628093/page-42

Comment: Well a direct link to the exact forum post would help more because other users may have identified some of them...

Comment: Some of them (at least 5)  can be found here with information  : https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/7/74477/2276865-1196881233075lg9.gif

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Relevant information aside, don't the site rules (or plagiarism laws) ***require*** that the original source be credited?

Comment: @user14111 Depends on the context of the source I think. It's always best to credit the source but if the sources license states it doesn't need to be credited there is no need.

Comment: @ProfesseurDronte, probably almost all of them, at lot seem to be the same source image, though the Borg cube has been rotated 90deg. The big stack on the right are just Star Fleet ships in size order.

Comment: I'm curious about the ship above B5: the rotating section looks too close to the back for an Omega class destroyer, and I don't think it's the Alexei Leonov either.

Comment: Addendum to @ProfesseurDronte comment https://orig00.deviantart.net/494a/f/2014/171/0/1/size_comparison___science_fiction_spaceships_by_dirkloechel-d6lfgdf.jpg

Comment: The two ships directly under B5's solar panels are from *Macross*, the *SDF Macross* itself and a Zentraedi ship.

Comment: B5 is not a ship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that this image comes from [Jeff Russell's STARSHIP DIMENSIONS](http://www.merzo.net/indexSD.html), or at least created by images from that site.  There you will find all of the various names and sources.

Starting from top left:

1. The Imperial Retribution Class Battleship BloodHawk, from Battlefleet Gothic, 7.5km long.
   Image created by John Reed
2. Star Destroyer, 1.6km, originally drawn by Chad Wilson (Blockade Runner also shown)
3. Cobra Class Destroyer BlackSkull, from Battlefleet Gothic, 1.5km long.
   Image created by John Reed
4. Trade Federation battleship from Star Wars, originally drawn by Chad Wilson
5. Mon Calamari cruiser, 1.3km
6. Borg Cube
7. Poseidon carrier From Babylon 5
8. Babylon 5
9. Event Horizon
10. Romulan D'Deridex - Star Trek: TNG
11. Macross Super Dimensional Fortress One
12. Zentraedi Nupetiet-Vergnitzs (Flagship), 4km, Originally designed by Kazutaka Miyatake, drawn by Jeff Russell
13. Deep Space Nine
14. Super Star Destroyer, Image originally drawn by Chad Wilson
15. Nostromo from Alien
16. Battlestar Galactica
17. Rodger-Young from the movie 'Starship Troopers'

Various real life buildings, aircraft, and ships included for scale.

I have not listed the various ships from Star Trek.